# Disable django form field for a given time

Tags: python, django

I want to disable django fields for 6 months after the date of update. I have saved update_time to a table.

```
updated_time = a.update_time
disabled_time = a.update_time + timedelta(180)
```

I want to diable field that updated:

```
self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

How can I disable `self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True` for `disabled_time`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your view and template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *compare*, and *substract* basic `datetime` objects and make some check at form initialization time:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
...
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # check if we already have a saved object and it's not older than 180 days
        if self.instance.pk and
                (datetime.now() - self.instance.update_time) < timedelta(180):
            self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

(Not really tested but should work as it is.)
Also note, that it is often convenient to keep `update_time` with [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) set to *True*.